# Problem with display 1080P website in Android TV app

Tags: android, html, android-studio, android-layout, webview

I'm trying to create an app that displays website using WebView for Android TV. I know the website works perfectly on PC, but for some reason when I'm running the app on TV The website is displayed in low resolution (looks like 720P). 
I think the problem is something with the resolution of the website, but I'm not sure if the problem is on the app side or at the website and I don't know how to fix that.

The XML code of the WebView is this:

```
<WebView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_webview"/>
```

And the Java code is this:

```
webView = view.findViewById(R.id.main_webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String URL)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
 webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Is there any particular way to display websites on Android TV that require more than this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See if `User-Agent` string matters, some websites do use it when determining optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google.com with your app and you can definitely see where is the problem if Google.com works perfectly then the problem is in your website